# Select random item with double bias

Tags: java, random

I have already read a lot of posts around this subject but I am not satisfied with what I have found.

I have a list of objects, lets call them "L".

"L" has two properties, "`L.small`" and "`L.big`".

I want to select a random "L", but bias the selection so that I am more likely to select objects with a lower "L.small" and a higher "L.big". So just to make it clear, it is the combination of a low "`L.small`" and a high "`L.big`" that make the object more attractive.

Here is an example:

Lets say the maximum possible `L.small` is 50. and the maximum `L.big` is 1000,000. So `L.small` is a random range of small values and `L.big` is a random range of big values.

L1.small = 1     //best possible .small

L1.big = 1000,000//best possible .big

L2.small = 50    //least desirable .small

L2.big = 1       //least desirable .big

L3.small = 25    //pretty average

L3.big = 500,000 //pretty average

In this example, L1 would be most likely to be chosen and L2 least likely, and L3 in between.

Also just to give more background, my real values are longs.

Comment: You've said about "more likely" and "less likely" - but *how* likely are these? Basically you need to provide some sort of weighting function to give each item a non-negative weight, at which point the rest of my answer applies. We can't really guess the weighting function... it could be `big - small + 100` for example, which would work for your sample data, but that may not be the weighting you really want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, I'd misinterpreted the question. The exact algorithm you use will depend on how you want things to be biased. For example, you could effectively just treat each object as having a "weight" of `big - small`... then add up all the weights of the items in the list:

```
int totalWeight = 0;
for (Foo foo : list)
{
    totalWeight += foo.getWeight();
}

// As usual, normally you'd reuse an existing instance
Random rng = new Random();
int value = rng.nextInt(totalWeight);

// Pick an item based on the random value we've chosen
for (Foo foo : list)
{
    if (value < foo.getWeight())
    {
        return foo;
    }
    value -= foo.getWeight();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. Apologies my question must not be well defined. First of all I want the whole object, not foo.small or foo.big, I want Foo. Also, I want *both* properties, .small and .big to be taken into consideration together so that an object with a very small foo.small and a very big foo.big is more likely to be chosen than one which has say an avergare foo.small and foo.big.

Comment: @zuki: Okay, I see... but please give a concrete example, including how much bias you want this to contribute.

Comment: @zuki: You should edit your *question* with the example, rather than putting it into comments. See my edit for an example approach.

Comment: @jon-skeet: Thanks, I have added an example to the question, I hope that helps. I can go into more detail if needed but I don't want to confuse the question with my background problem.

Comment: @jon-skeet: Dude, that looks exactly like my code right now! Maybe the really tricky part then is combining `foo.small` and `foo.big` into one single `foo.weight` value which is representative of the preference to one being low and one being big

Comment: @zuki: Yes, exactly. One *possible* weighting function would be `big - small` possibly with some constant as well (e.g. `big - small + 100`) but we can't really tell you what it should be. Note that you don't necessarily need the value stored in a *field* - just a property which returns the weight based on the other fields.

Comment: @jon-skeet: Agreed. I have edited the question again with a bit more detail. I can't think of the best way to combine my properties into a single weight, I am now thinking that I might have to do some sort of 2 step process where I select a sublist based on the first bias, and the select from that result based on the second bias.

Comment: @jon-skeet: Accepting your answer based on the fact that I think you have actually answered the question and I have now effectively proposed a new question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to generate random variables with non-uniform probability density functions (PDFs)?  If so, you may be interested in [*inverse transform sampling*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), which allows you to transform a uniformly-distributed random number (such as you might get from `java.util.Random`), to one with an arbitrary PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it's going to take me some time to consume the contents :-) I think it is overkill for my purpose... also my data could be coming in realtime, streaming so it has to be very performant.